# Telerik controls  - .NET Version compatibility issues

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, frameworks, web

I enhanced an old website just a bit, but the problem is I used telerik controls which requires a higher version of .net than the original website has. The website is hosted externally, and I only have access to the website itself through an ftp site.

My question is what is the easiest way to set up this site to be able to handle .net 4.0? I believe 4.0 is already backwards compatible. I'm almost sure that the version of IIS on the old server is running .net 4.0.

Thank you in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't run .NET applications that depend on different versions of the .NET runtime within the same application pool. Unfortunately, if the only control you have is via FTP, you have no means of configuring the application pool for this or any other application. You'll have to ask your hosting company to set up an application pool for the directory for this site so that you can run .NET 4.0.

Comment: Ok, once I get the host to set up the application pool will this tag in my web config be all I need to complete the task? <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"> I guess now I'm asking what needs to be done to set up the website to use the framework?

Comment: It depends on the version of IIS that they're using. If the version of IIS allows them to specify a framework version, they'll need to do that. If it doesn't, then it uses the first of the first-loaded application, in which case all you need to do is modify your Web.config in the way that you mentioned.